# Unique set of undirected edges

Tags: c++11

I want to create a set (mathematically speaking, not std::set) of unique elements in C++. My elements are `std::pair<int, int>` and they represent an edge. Because those edges are not directed, I don't want to have duplicates like (3,4) and (4,3). How can I achieve this in C++ ?

Comment: Have a function addDiirectedEdge(int a, intb), and inside it, and a, b and b, a edges. So you only have to call one function and there is no redundant operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another solution, with the compare function as lambda expression.

```
using Edge = pair<int, int>;

std::set<Edge, std::function<bool(const Edge &, const Edge &)>> edges(
    [](const Edge &a, const Edge &b)
    {
        const int x = min(a.first, a.second);
        const int y = min(b.first, b.second);
        if (x < y)
            return true;
        else if (y > x)
            return false;
        else
            return max(a.first, a.second) < max(b.first, b.second);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
using Edge = std::pair<int, int>;
struct CompareEdges {
  bool operator()(const Edge& a, const Edge& b) const {
    return Normalize(a) < Normalize(b);
  }
 private:
  Edge Normalize(const Edge& e) {
    if (e.first <= e.second) return e;
    return {e.second, e.first};
  }
};

std::set<Edge, CompareEdges> SetOfEdges;
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do this inline with a lambda expression without having to make a struct ?

Comment: You can't, not easily. `std::set` wants the comparator as a template parameter, and lambda's type cannot be named. You could do something unwieldy with `decltype` - but why would you want to? What's wrong with a named class?

Comment: Where am I supposed to declare that named class ? I only use this set within a function.

Comment: You can define a class within a function, if you are so inclined.

Comment: What does `{3,5} < {5,2}` do exactly ?

Comment: Lexicographical comparison. Roughly, `return a.first < b.first || (a.first == b.first && a.second < b.second);`

Comment: I was gonna say just now, that my IDE is kinda broken. This is a bug of the IDE.

Comment: In this situation does it matter if I use `[&]` vs `[]` ?

Comment: No it does not. Your lambda is not capturing anything.